# How to consume tap events for Map in CollapsingToolbar

Tags: google-maps, flutter, scrollview, here-api, gesture

I want to put a MapWidget into a `FlexibleSpaceBar` (inside a `SliverAppBar` inside a `NestedScrollView`) to show it in a Collapsable Toolbar. My widget tree looks like this:

```
Scaffold
 |
 |- NestedScrollView
     |
     |- SliverAppBar
     |   |
     |   |- FlexibleSpaceBar
     |       |
     |       |- Map
     |
     |- ListView
```

The problem is that the `NestedScrollView`consumes all the Gesture events and I cannot use pinch-to-zoom any more on the `Map`. What's the best way to solve this?

Here's some code:

```
class ListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> list = List<int>.generate(10, (i) => i + 1);
    return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return [
          SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 250.0,
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              snap: false,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('Second Screen'),
                background: MapWidget(),
              )),
        ];
      },
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          int item = list[index];
          return Text('item $item');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [GoogleMap](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) as your MapWidget, perhaps this can help:

```
gestureRecognizers: Set()
  ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
  ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
      () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
```

With this you can use pan and drag gestures inside your Map Widget.

I looked a bit through the other gesture recognizer options, the closest thing to pinch-to-zoom was *ScaleGestureRecognizer* but I didn't test it.

Comment: I'm using HereMaps but will try to find a similar option there